# How to implement the DriverSetup class in Selenium Webdriver framework

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

How to implement the DriverSetup class in Selenium Webdriver framework..
Currently I am launching driver in @BeforeClass for each testng test class, please let me know if how can I implement the common driverLaunch/driverSetup class for all test
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: if you want for each test to launch a different browser through setup, use `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeMethod` of TestNG to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u mean a common setup for all classes? If so create a base class and extend it in every test class. In Base class have @BeforeClass to do the required.
It would be somewhat like:

```
public class BaseClass {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // or any driver u want, or based on requirement create a if else scenario
    }
}
```

And in Testclass do like:

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass {
    // your class body with tests here
}
```

So whenever u run ur tests through testng it will call the setUp method in BaseClass and setup browser for u.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Worked well for me and able to get driver instance in Listener classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Init your WebDriver in @BeforeTest or in @BeforeSuite and close it in @AfterTest or @AfterSuite. So in this case every test method will get run in the same browser.